# EXT4-fs error after Ubuntu 17.04 upgrade on Patriot burst drive

Tags: 18.04, ssd, ext4

I saw some solutions to the Samsung drive but nothing for this one .
I tried installing their utility:

```
sudo nvme list
[sudo] password for user: 
Node             SN                   Model                                    Namespace Usage                      Format           FW Rev  
---------------- -------------------- ---------------------------------------- --------- -------------------------- ---------------- --------
```

nothing shows up for my drive.

here is the smartctl:

```
$ sudo smartctl -data -A /dev/sda
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-4.15.0-45-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       145
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       63
168 Unknown_Attribute       0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
170 Unknown_Attribute       0x0003   057   057   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       482
173 Unknown_Attribute       0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       31
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0023   067   067   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       33 (Min/Max 33/33)
218 Unknown_Attribute       0x000b   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
231 Temperature_Celsius     0x0013   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       100
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       52


Here is Fdisk -L:

Disk /dev/sda: 223.6 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x9a235438

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048 343861247 343859200  164G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       343863294 468860927 124997634 59.6G  5 Extended

and sudo lshw -C disk

  *-disk
       description: ATA Disk
       product: Patriot Burst
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sda
       version: 91.2
       serial: C44207870E6305356456
       size: 223GiB (240GB)
       capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
       configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512 signature=9a235438
```

Comment: Its happening every time I use the computer. I'm getting really annoyed and there is nothing I can do about. Suddenly the computer just goes to read only and slowly all the icons start dissapearing until finally there nothing else to do but to press the reset button for 10 seconds or watch the window saying how EXT4 had an erro in some inode or that it is read only blah blah.